# Count how many entries in array with specific name and save to use it later

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, count

I am trying to find a way to count how many entries of each type I have in this array:

```
var types = [
  "loc_67249556",
  "loc_52558678",
  "loc_62658330",
  "gra_59669755",
  "gra_59289309"
]
```

The "type" that I mean is the 3 first letters of each entry.
I used a for to loop over the array and extract the 3 first letters:

```
for (var i = 0; i < types.length; k++) {
    var tp= types[k].split('_');
    tp = tp[0];
}
```

This will output the 3 first letters, but how can I count them and save in a way that I could use it later?

Something like a new array with the types and how many times they appear in the first array, similar to this:

```
var types_count = [
  {
    type: "loc",
    qnt: 3
  },
  {
    type: "gra",
    qnt: 2
  }
]
```

Also, the "types" that I have in total are 51 different types of entries, all starting with 3 letters like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array.map [check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
    var getcount = function (types) {
        var result = [];
        types.map(obj => {
            var key = obj.split('_')[0];
            var tempArr = result.filter(item => item.key == key);
            if (tempArr.length > 0) {
                tempArr[0].count = tempArr[0].count + 1;
            } else {
                var tempitem = {
                    count: 1,
                    key: key
                };
                result.push(tempitem);
            }
        });
        return result;
    }

    var types = [
        "loc_67249556",
        "loc_52558678",
        "loc_62658330",
        "gra_59669755",
        "gra_59289309"
    ]
    //to get result call it 
    var newArr = getcount(types);
    console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Add the code to code snippet mate. This will be easier for people to see it working :)

Answer (score 5):

Use `reduce` to extract the first 3 letters, adding to an accumulator object indexed by type, then get the values of that object:

```js
const types = [
  "loc_67249556",
  "loc_52558678",
  "loc_62658330",
  "gra_59669755",
  "gra_59289309"
];

const typeCount = types.reduce((a, str) => {
  const type = str.slice(0, 3);
  if (!a[type]) a[type] = { type, count: 0 };
  a[type].count++;
  return a;
}, {})
console.log(Object.values(typeCount));
```

Comment: You could do the assignment with this also. a[type] = { type, count: a[type] ? a[type].count + 1 : 1 };

Comment: Yep, that's an option, but it would create a new object on every iteration

Comment: So memory wise it's not very efficient to use the spread syntax on such cases?

Comment: I suppose either works, not creating more intermediate objects helps a bit, but it wouldn't matter unless there was a ton of data to go through (in which case it'd be better to use a `for` loop, whose speed can't be beat by anything)

Comment: Can I add the `Object.values(typeCount))` to a variable to loop later?

Comment: @RogerHN Sure, you might consider avoiding putting the type inside the object at all, and instead just have an object whose keys are the types, and the values are the counts. eg `{ loc: 3, gra: 2 }` and then iterate over the `entries` to get both the key and the count at once

Comment: I have some difficulties iterating over entries like this, I am more used to iterate over entries like the one's from my example, I always get confuse when I need to iterate over a single entry like `{loc:3, gra: 2}`

Comment: @RogerHN `Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => { /* do stuff with key and value */ });`

Comment: A for loop wouldn't be more fast/efficient? `for (var i = 0; i < Object.values(typeCount).length; i++) { }`

Comment: @RogerHN Faster, but array methods make for much clearer code - unlike `for` loops, they don't require manual iteration, they have automatic abstraction, and are functional. Best to prefer clear code over everything else, at least until a problem appears

Answer (score 3):

You can try this with help of `reduce()`

```js
var types = [
  "loc_67249556",
  "loc_52558678",
  "loc_62658330",
  "gra_59669755",
  "gra_59289309"
];

let op = Object.values(types.reduce((op,curr)=>{
  let temp = curr.substr(0,3);
  if( op[temp] ){
    op[temp]['count']++;
  } else {
    op[temp] ={
      'type': temp,
      'count': 1
    }
  }
  return op;
},{}))
console.log(op);
```

Comment: the result object  `op`  is not in the form @RogerHN  wanted

Answer (score 1):

if type_count exist with some values of a prévious work (or  not):

```js
var types = [
  "loc_67249556",
  "loc_52558678",
  "loc_62658330",
  "gra_59669755",
  "gra_59289309"
];

var types_count = [{type:'bef', qnt: 5}]; // values from a previous op
// or var types_count = []; // empty


// update types_count with new values and increase previous count
types.forEach(function(elm) {
  let
    tp = elm.split('_')[0],
    ix = types_count.findIndex(e=>e.type===tp)
  ;
  if (ix<0) { types_count.push( {  type: tp,  qnt: 1 } )
  } else    { types_count[ix].qnt++; }
});

// because there is [sorting] in your tags:
types_count.sort((a,b) => (a.type > b.type) ? 1 : ((b.type > a.type) ? -1 : 0));

console.log( types_count );
```